in pluto_grid, PlutoColumn renderer widget "unable to input"
For details please see github issues
Use TextField to enter text.
but in pluto_grid, PlutoColumn renderer widget TextField "unable to input"
There is no response to the input
enter image description here

Flutter version

3.24.2


PlutoGrid version


8.0.0


OS


Windows 11

